# Want the previous date selected on the datepicker. (android)

Tags: java, android, datepicker, timepicker

I have a datepicker and a time picker in a custom dialog. If I change the date on the datepicker it gets updated on the Textview. But when I select the datepicker again, it gives today's date. I want the previous selected date to show on the datepicker. 
This is my code. Pls help!!

```
from.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            picker = new Dialog(getActivity());
            picker.setContentView(R.layout.datetime);
            picker.setTitle("Select Date and Time");
            datep = (DatePicker) picker.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
            timep = (TimePicker) picker.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

            set = (Button) picker.findViewById(R.id.btnSet);
            set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    month = datep.getMonth() + 1;
                    day = datep.getDayOfMonth();
                    year = datep.getYear();
                    hour = timep.getCurrentHour();
                    minute = timep.getCurrentMinute();
                    from.setText(year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " "
                            + hour + ":" + minute);
                    picker.dismiss();



                }
            });
            picker.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Before showing u have to set previous date value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. Just set it outside by scope of the button which shows the button...

```
    picker = new Dialog(getActivity());
    picker.setContentView(R.layout.datetime);
    picker.setTitle("Select Date and Time");
    datep = (DatePicker) picker.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    timep = (TimePicker) picker.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);


from.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            set = (Button) picker.findViewById(R.id.btnSet);
            set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    //datep.updateDate(year, month, day);

                    month = datep.getMonth() + 1;
                    day = datep.getDayOfMonth();
                    year = datep.getYear();
                    hour = timep.getCurrentHour();
                    minute = timep.getCurrentMinute();
                    from.setText(year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " "
                            + hour + ":" + minute);
                    picker.dismiss();



                }
            });
            picker.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1) save thre previous selected day, month and year in a variable - and set them into the DatePickerDialog

2) get the saved date from your text - and set them into the DatePickerDialog

Comment: I understood waht you're trying to say but how do i do this??? i am new to android..

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a OnDateSetListener on the DatePicker Dialog, something like this :

```
/**
 * Initialize DatePickerDialog
 */
private void initDatePicker() {
    myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }
    };

    dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, 
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    dateDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
}
```

Once you initialise this method, it will automatically show the date on the datepicker once it has been set. (: